# Calculate signature speed/velocity having timestamp and position

Tags: position, timestamp, velocity

I'm writing a signature software (you sign through a tablet and it processes you signature).
I have for each point pressed by the pen its position (.getx() and .gety()) and its timestamp (.getTime()).  How can i calculate an appropriate "signing speed"? Witch kind of formula should I use? 
It is enough to do distance/time (amount of lines written between the points/ time to write them)? Or should I find the vectorial average speed?

Thanks to all who wants to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend find the total New York City distance and divide by the elapsed time.

Let's assume you have lots of points

Pseudo Code

```
distance = 0
for each point after the first
  distance += abs(point(i).x - point(i-1).x) + abs(point(i).y - point(i-1).y)
speed = distance/(endtime - starttime)
```

I like the NYC distance versus the sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY).  Is is faster to compute and not really all relatively different - IMHO